# Loading from data from plist gives me the values in the wrong order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a plist file where I load key - value pairs. However the order that I have in the plist file does not match the order it is in the code.

I have the following

KEY -- VALUE
Fartsgrense60 -- VALUE
Fartsgrense70 -- VALUE
Annet -- VALUE

and in the program it is Annet, Fartsgrense70 and Fartsgrense60. Why is it so, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define your plist as an array made up of dictionaries for for key pair. Alternatively you could store your dictionary in the plist as well as an array of the key in the order you want them.

Answer (score 0):

How do you load the pairs? Directly into an NSDictionary? That's a hash table, which does not make any guarantees about preserving any kind of order of its elements. If order is significant, you need to use a container which preserves it.